# Nodes with different shapes in pygraphviz

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

I'm trying to visualize an automaton in `pygraphviz`, like the example in [graphviz documentation](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Gallery/directed/fsm.html):

[image: Finite Automaton example in graphviz docs]

I've found that node shapes can be changed like:

```
A.node_attr['shape']='circle' # A is a pygraphviz AGraph
```

This changes the shape of all nodes, but I want to use different node shapes for different nodes (some `'circle'` and some `'doublecircle'`). Any advice for doing that?

*Note: I'm using `pygraphviz` because I want to use `networkx` graph objects and those can be converted to `AGraph` objects of `pygraphviz`. Also, apparently `networkx` can't produce graph visualizations like this.*

Comment: Best to show a small complete MWE that indicates your problems i.e. an example with just a couple of nodes / edges.

Comment: @albert You're right, but the whole point of my question is about using different shapes for nodes and if someone shows me how to do it for just two nodes, it suffices.

Comment: As I don't know pygraphviz I cannot advise without seeing some code. In case I see some code I might give a clue (I expect that either each node has also an attribute shape or otherwise it is possible to set first the node shape for e.g. the double circle nodes and after this for the circle nodes (analogous to the example in the documentation you mentioned (and the gv file mentioned there).

Comment: Have a look at the documentation http://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/pygraphviz-1.5/tutorial.html#nodes-and-edges, I think under the heading Attributes there is exactly the information required (and I was pointing at even without doing a simple Google search for "graphviz documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each node in the graph is an instance of `Node` class and nodes attributes are set with `ItemAttribute`. This means you can change the attributes of nodes separately. Thus, you only need to access the nodes. This is possible vs `iternodes`, an iterator on nodes of `AGraph`. Here's an example of using `networkx` and `pygraphviz` together and changing the node's attributes:

```py
import networkx as nx
import pygraphviz as pgv

G = nx.DiGraph()

nodes = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
edges = {('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'c')}

G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)

A = nx.nx_agraph.to_agraph(G)

shapes = ['circle', 'box']
for i, node in enumerate(A.iternodes()):
        node.attr['shape'] = shapes[i%2]
A.layout()
A.draw('graph.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

All the information is contained in the pygraphviz documentation (http://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/pygraphviz-1.5/tutorial.html#nodes-and-edges) in the paragraph Attributes where it states:

To set the default attributes for graphs, nodes, and edges use the graph_attr, node_attr, and edge_attr dictionaries

> > > G.graph_attr['label']='Name of graph'
> > >       G.node_attr['shape']='circle'
> > >       G.edge_attr['color']='red'

Graph attributes can be set when initializing the graph

> > > G=pgv.AGraph(ranksep='0.1')

Attributes can be added when adding nodes or edges,

> > > G.add_node(1, color='red')
> > >       G.add_edge('b','c',color='blue')

or through the node or edge attr dictionaries,

> > > n=G.get_node(1)
> > >       n.attr['shape']='box'
> > >
> > > e=G.get_edge('b','c')
> > >       e.attr['color']='green'

Comment: Thanks @albert ! `get_node()` was what I was looking for.